# Unexpected token LEFT BRACE({) at position 4

Tags: java, json, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I'm studying Spring Framework and I'm parsing JSON data but it shows:

> Unexpected token LEFT BRACE({) at position 4.

However eclipse did not show any indication of an error.

Here is my controller source:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/listcall.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void home( @RequestParam("val") String id, HttpServletRequest request , HttpServletResponse response) throws JsonIOException, IOException, ParseException {
    response.setCharacterEncoding("utf8");
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    String valuewhat = id ;
    JsonArray jarraySend = new JsonArray();
    //System.out.println(request.getParameter("val"));
    JSONParser parse = new JSONParser();
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("D:\\Spring\\sworkspace\\Calendar\\src\\main\\resources\\somelist.json");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(fileReader);
    String inline = null;
    while(sc.hasNext())
    {
    inline+=sc.nextLine();
    }
    JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parse.parse(inline);
    JSONArray jarray_1 = (JSONArray) json.get("listing_property_type_information");

    for(int i=0;i<jarray_1.size();i++) {
        JSONObject jsonobj_1 = (JSONObject)jarray_1.get(i);

        //JsonArray jsonarr_2 = (JsonArray) jsonobj_1.get("property_type_groups");
        jarray_1 = (JSONArray) jsonobj_1.get("property_type_groups");
        for(int j=0;j<jarray_1.size();j++) {
            JSONObject jsonobj_2 = (JSONObject) jarray_1.get(j);

            //something do.....

        }
    }


    //jarray.add(json);
    new Gson().toJson(jarray_1, response.getWriter());
}
```

I've been practicing to mimic functions like the AirBNB site.

JSON file is located at:

https://www.airbnb.co.kr/become-a-host/room <-Here is a scrolling copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at your `inline` variable.And you should declare this variable like this`String inline = "";` rather than `String inline = null;` which will make the string you spliced start with "null"

Answer (score 0):

This means your json is bad. Eclipse cannot catch it because it is a runtime error.

Comment: oh eclipse is not  catch json ... But i cat understand sometime showing error to json file   it's ecilpse bug?

Answer (score -1):

```
public static  String fetchFromJSONNext() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, org.json.simple.parser.ParseException  {



//      String filename=System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\com\\test\\mtcn1.json";

    String filename=System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\com\\test\\mtcn1.json";


    //System.out.println(request.getParameter("val"));
    JSONParser parse = new JSONParser();
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filename);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(fileReader);
    String inline ="";
    String sj ="";

    while(sc.hasNext()){
        inline+=sc.nextLine();

        JSONObject jsonobj_2 = (JSONObject) parse.parse(inline);


                //something do.....

                Object g=jsonobj_2.get("result");
                JSONObject h = (JSONObject) g;
                sj=(String) h.get("wutaf_rpcmsg");

    }
    return sj;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.